# rarfile поднимает ошибку Failed the read enough data: req=65536 got=0

Tags: python

Этот вопрос является [точной копией вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71308687/problem-when-using-rarfile-in-python-badrarfile-failed-the-read-enough-data-r), однако ответа на него всё ещё нет, и мне не помогли ответы из этого вопроса.

Если кратко, эта ошибка возникает при попытке распаковать Rar архив с помощью `rarfile`. То есть вызов функции `extract` поднимает `BadRarFile` с сообщением `"Failed the read enough data: req=65536 got=0"`. Я долго копался в исходном коде, и обнаружил, что ошибка возникает при попытке прочитать из дескриптора конвейера утилиты `unrar` - она молчит (не очень полезно) :(

---

Вот соседний файл распаковывает, а на этом файле выдаёт ошибку. Я гарантирую, что:

- `rarfile` с помощью `pip` установлен
- `unrar` с помощью `pip` установлен
- `unrar` с помощью `apt` установлен
- да, корректно работает в большинстве случаев, это гейзенбаг
- да, в качестве утилиты для распаковки `rarfile` корректно распознаёт и использует `unrar`.

Любая помощь, пожалуйста.

Comment: а эти тикеты смотрели уже: https://github.com/markokr/rarfile/pull/69 ?

Comment: @strawdog да, я смотрел исходный код `rarfile`, я обнаружил, что разделитель в заголовках не зависит от ОС. Я использую правильные разделители. Кроме того, заголовки архива читаются нормально. Файл "test data — копия/Инк._Ныдинская.txt" превосходно извлекается, в то время, как файл "test data — копия/Инк._Медвежья.txt" - нет

Comment: А они рядом лежат. Это соседние файлы в архиве.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что `unrar`, который я скачал - это одноимённая библиотека, а не оригинал. Оригинал можно скачать [здесь](https://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm). Из-за этого `rarfile` выбирал библиотеку `unar` вместо `unrar`. Я проверял это 2 недели назад, и это было правдой, но кое-что изменилось за 2 недели. Проверить это было чрезвычайно трудно, поскольку проект находится в контейнере и я не имею root прав на сервере. Мне пришлось 2 дня выяснять в чём проблема :(